# Why does my laptop battery only charge to 95%?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, battery-life

My laptop ([MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH](https://us-store.msi.com/GS76-Stealth-11UH-078?search=%2011UH-078)) is plugged all the time. I've noticed that the battery charge is 95%. Why not 100%?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Likely, manufacturer's choice to extend the battery's useful lifetime, as opposed to getting the maximum run time. Cycling lithium batteries to 100% (or far worse, depleting them below 10 %) significantly cuts the number of time the battery can be charged. The laptop I'm using now limits charge to only *80%* for that reason.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks, yes I wonder if this 95% stems from some intentional limitation or battery wear.

Answer (score 1):

> My laptop (MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH) is plugged all the time. I've
> noticed that the battery charge is 95%.

Leaving a laptop plugged in this way is definitely not good for the battery.

If you wish to leave a laptop always plugged in, your laptop needs to support Battery Threshold Management. This is manufacturer-supplied software that works with BIOS (UEFI) and keeps the battery charged to 80%.  This is the generally accepted charge level for always plugged in. Charging stops at 80%.  I use this feature on my laptop (Lenovo).

If your laptop does not have this feature, you should not leave it plugged in.

In your situation, try resetting the battery.

Charge to full, disconnect, and allow to discharge to about 10%.  Reconnect and charge to full. Batteries should not be regularly totally discharged, so just do this once.

See if (after a full restart) charge goes back to 100% or very near.

Then (again if no Battery Threshold software) do not leave plugged in all the time. Charge to 80% and unplug; repeat.